# Converting CSV to JSON in bash

Tags: json, bash, csv, unix, jq

Trying to convert a CSV file into a JSON

Here is two sample lines :

```
-21.3214077;55.4851413;Ruizia cordata
-21.3213078;55.4849803;Cossinia pinnata
```

I would like to get something like :

```
"occurrences": [
                 {
                "position": [-21.3214077, 55.4851413],
                "taxo": {
                    "espece": "Ruizia cordata"
                 },
                 ...
             }]
```

Here is my script :

```
    echo '"occurences": [ '

cat se.csv | while read -r line
  do
      IFS=';' read -r -a array <<< $line;
      echo -n -e '{ "position": [' ${array[0]}
      echo -n -e ',' ${array[1]} ']'
      echo -e ', "taxo": {"espece":"' ${array[2]} '"'
done
echo "]";
```

I get really strange results :

```
   "occurences": [ 
 ""position": [ -21.3214077, 55.4851413 ], "taxo": {"espece":" Ruizia cordata
 ""position": [ -21.3213078, 55.4849803 ], "taxo": {"espece":" Cossinia pinnata
```

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `jq`, or otherwise JSON-aware tooling? Generating JSON (or other structured-data serializations) with string concatenation is... error-prone at best.

Comment: Other than that, there are a *lot* of bad practices here. You're leaving out a bunch of essential quoting, such that if one of your values contained a whitespace-surrounded `*` it would be replaced with a list of filenames. You're using `-e` unnecessarily, so that if your JSON data contained a `\n` sequence (which, in JSON, should be represented as exactly those characters) it would be replaced with a literal newline; **and** by virtue of `-e` your code won't work correctly on shells with a [POSIX: standard `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: re: the missing quoting, by the way -- consider making a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The right tool for this job is [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

```
jq -Rsn '
  {"occurrences":
    [inputs
     | . / "\n"
     | (.[] | select(length > 0) | . / ";") as $input
     | {"position": [$input[0], $input[1]], "taxo": {"espece": $input[2]}}]}
' <se.csv
```

emits, given your input:

```
{
  "occurences": [
    {
      "position": [
        "-21.3214077",
        "55.4851413"
      ],
      "taxo": {
        "espece": "Ruizia cordata"
      }
    },
    {
      "position": [
        "-21.3213078",
        "55.4849803"
      ],
      "taxo": {
        "espece": "Cossinia pinnata"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

By the way, a less-buggy version of your original script might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

items=( )
while IFS=';' read -r lat long pos _; do
  printf -v item '{ "position": [%s, %s], "taxo": {"espece": "%s"}}' "$lat" "$long" "$pos"
  items+=( "$item" )
done <se.csv

IFS=','
printf '{"occurrences": [%s]}\n' "${items[*]}"
```

Note:

- There's absolutely no point using `cat` to pipe into a loop (and [good reasons not to](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)); thus, we're using a redirection (`<`) to open the file directly as the loop's stdin.
- `read` can be passed a list of destination variables; there's thus no need to read into an array (or *first* to read into a string, and then to generate a heresting and to read from that into an array). The `_` at the end ensures that extra columns are discarded (by putting them into the dummy variable named `_`) rather than appended to `pos`.
- `"${array[*]}"` generates a string by concatenating elements of `array` with the character in `IFS`; we can thus use this to ensure that commas are present in the output only when they're needed.
- `printf` is used in preference to `echo`, as advised in the APPLICATION USAGE section of [the specification for `echo` itself](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).
- This is still inherently buggy since it's generating JSON via string concatenation. Don't use it.

Comment: Thx, didn't know jq. But I cannot figure it out how to input my CSV. What's $s at the end of your line ?

Comment: Oh -- that was reading from a string, not a file. Sorry 'bout that, left it in from testing.

Comment: actually, I edited that out a while ago -- could you refresh to be sure you're seeing the current version of the answer?

Comment: that is some beautiful stuff, thanks... i like the use of inputs there.

Answer (score 94):

Here's a python one-liner/script that'll do the trick:

```sh
cat my.csv | python -c 'import csv, json, sys; print(json.dumps([dict(r) for r in csv.DictReader(sys.stdin)]))'
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution -- it does the trick for any and all payloads. The jq version is a one-off and requires painstakingly matching the schema

Comment: I love this idea. I modified slightly to write to file... `cat in.csv | python -c 'import csv, json, sys; f = open("out.json", "x"); f.write(json.dumps([dict(r) for r in csv.DictReader(sys.stdin)])); f.close()'`

Comment: to write it to a file just add `| > filename.json` at the end. Like this: `cat my.csv | python -c 'import csv, json, sys; print(json.dumps([dict(r) for r in csv.DictReader(sys.stdin)]))' | > my.json`

Comment: @btk, no, it shouldn't ... it doesn't address the need to named entities in the json output at all.  It *may* do the right thing if the CVS has named headers (I don't have the data or time to create it to verify that it would).

Comment: @tink it works when all headers are present **only**.

Comment: thanks for proving my point that this **shouldn't** be the accepted answer then, @Fravadona :)

Comment: @tink imo it's way easier to add headers to the .csv file than futz around with a complicated jq query

Comment: I don't think the `dict` is needed and you could just do `list(csv.DictReader(sys.stdin))` instead.

Comment: @K14 somehow adding the output part gave me an error " Broken pipe"

Comment: Doesn't support csv's with `"` in them.

Comment: TBH there are times when I got pretty fed up with futzing around with `jq` @btk, not lying

Comment: With bigger files you want a "lazy" version: `python -c 'import csv, json, sys; any(map(print, (json.dumps(dict(r)) for r in csv.DictReader(sys.stdin))))'`. It uses generators so it does not build the whole list, but it prints a JSONL output instead of a single JSON array.

Answer (score 23):

The accepted answer uses `jq` to parse the input. This works but `jq` doesn't handle escapes i.e. input from a CSV produced from Excel or similar tools is quoted like this:

```
foo,"bar,baz",gaz
```

will result in the incorrect output, as jq will see 4 fields, not 3.

One option is to use tab-separated values instead of comma (as long as your input data doesn't contain tabs!), along with the accepted answer.

Another option is to combine your tools, and use the best tool for each part: a CSV parser for reading the input and turning it into JSON, and `jq` for transforming the JSON into the target format.

The python-based [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will intelligently parse the CSV, and comes with a tool `csvjson` which will do a much better job of turning the CSV into JSON. This can then be piped through jq to convert the flat JSON output by csvkit into the target form.

With the data provided by the OP, for the desired output, this as as simple as:

```
csvjson --no-header-row  |
  jq '.[] | {occurrences: [{ position: [.a, .b], taxo: {espece: .c}}]}'
```

Note that csvjson automatically detects `;` as the delimiter, and without a header row in the input, assigns the json keys as `a`, `b`, and `c`.

The same also applies to writing *to* CSV files -- `csvkit` can read a JSON array or new-line delimited JSON, and intelligently output a CSV via `in2csv`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I knew there had to be a better way than parsing CSV with `jq`!

Comment: In my opinion `csvjson` is the best approach for this since it also can infer the data types, and not treat numbers as string, avoiding to add double quotes in it.

Answer (score 13):

John Kerl's [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) tool has this built-in:

```
mlr --c2j --jlistwrap cat INPUT.csv > OUTPUT.json
```

Comment: I love 'jq' but this is really nice, at least for converting a column-header carrying CSV to JSON. @richardkmiller

Answer (score 6):

Here is an article on the subject: https://infiniteundo.com/post/99336704013/convert-csv-to-json-with-jq

It also uses JQ, but a bit different approach using `split()` and `map()`.

```
jq --slurp --raw-input \
   'split("\n") | .[1:] | map(split(";")) |
      map({
         "position": [.[0], .[1]],
         "taxo": {
             "espece": .[2]
          }
      })' \
  input.csv > output.json
```

It doesn't handle separator escaping, though.

Comment: This is a good general approach! Perhaps you might edit to work with the OP's data structure? (Or would a 3rd-party edit doing so be welcome?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I gave it a shot, but not tested - feel free to fix/improve.

Comment: Needed some minor tweaks -- changing from ',' to ';' as the separator, changing `".[3]"` to `.[2]`; and `--raw-output` wasn't serving any purpose (it's ignored when output isn't a string).

Comment: Also, the `.[1:]` (skipping the first line) is only appropriate if input has a header; that was true in the blog post, but I'm not sure it's true here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, how would you parse the headers and then made the map automatically? Imagine you have different CSV files with different columns and want the JSON object keys derived from the header. Does `jq` have some kind of variables? Or perhaps an extra call to `jq ... .[:1] to fill a Bash array, somehow?

Comment: Yes, jq does have variables.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the Ruby one-liner solution:

```
ruby -r json -r csv -e 'puts CSV.parse(STDIN, headers:true).map(&:to_h).to_json' < INPUT.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/) (mlr)

```
mlr --implicit-csv-header --icsv --fs ';' --ojson label position,taxo,espece example.csv
```

which will produce the following

```
[
{
  "position": -21.3214077,
  "taxo": 55.4851413,
  "espece": "Ruizia cordata"
},
{
  "position": -21.3213078,
  "taxo": 55.4849803,
  "espece": "Cossinia pinnata"
}
]
```

or if you use `--ojsonl` (JSON line) instead of plain JSON will generate the following

```
{"position": -21.3214077, "taxo": 55.4851413, "espece": "Ruizia cordata"}
{"position": -21.3213078, "taxo": 55.4849803, "espece": "Cossinia pinnata"}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, if your jq has the `inputs` built-in filter (available since jq 1.5), then it is better to use it rather than the -s command-line option.

Here in any case is a solution using `inputs`.  This solution is also variable-free.

```
{"occurrences":
  [inputs
   | select(length > 0)
   | . / ";"
   | {"position": [.[0], .[1]], 
      "taxo": {"espece": .[2]}} ]}
```

### SSV, CSV, and all that

The above of course assumes that the file has semicolon-separated fields in each line, and that there are none of the complications associated with CSV files.

If the input has fields that are strictly delimited by a single character, then jq should have no problems handling it.  Otherwise, it might be best to use a tool that can reliably convert to the TSV (tab-separated value) format, which jq can handle directly.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `jq` solution does not handle CSV escaping, column names at the first line, commented-out lines and other common CSV "features", I have extended the [CSV Cruncher](https://github.com/OndraZizka/csv-cruncher) tool to allow reading CSV and writing it as JSON. It's not exactly "Bash", but neither is `jq` :)

It's primarily a CSV-as-SQL processing app, so it's not completely trivial, but here is the trick:

```
./crunch -in myfile.csv -out output.csv --json -sql 'SELECT * FROM myfile'
```

It also allows output as *JSON object per line* or *proper JSON array*. See the documentation.

It's in beta quality, so all feedback or pull requests are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) together with some XQuery magic can do this too:

```
xidel -s input.csv --xquery '
  {
    "occurrences":for $x in tokenize($raw,"\n") let $a:=tokenize($x,";") return {
      "position":[
        $a[1],
        $a[2]
      ],
      "taxo":{
        "espece":$a[3]
      }
    }
  }
'
```

```
{
  "occurrences": [
    {
      "position": ["-21.3214077", "55.4851413"],
      "taxo": {
        "espece": "Ruizia cordata"
      }
    },
    {
      "position": ["-21.3213078", "55.4849803"],
      "taxo": {
        "espece": "Cossinia pinnata"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go crazy, you can write a parser using jq. Here's my implementation which can be thought of as the inverse of the `@csv` filter. Throw this into your .jq file.

```
def do_if(pred; update):
    if pred then update else . end;
def _parse_delimited($_delim; $_quot; $_nl; $_skip):
    [($_delim, $_quot, $_nl, $_skip)|explode[]] as [$delim, $quot, $nl, $skip] |
    [0,1,2,3,4,5] as [$s_start,$s_next_value,$s_read_value,$s_read_quoted,$s_escape,$s_final] |
    def _append($arr; $value):
        $arr + [$value];
    def _do_start($c):
        if $c == $nl then
            [$s_start, null, null, _append(.[3]; [""])]
        elif $c == $delim then
            [$s_next_value, null, [""], .[3]]
        elif $c == $quot then
            [$s_read_quoted, [], [], .[3]]
        else
            [$s_read_value, [$c], [], .[3]]
        end;
    def _do_next_value($c):
        if $c == $nl then
            [$s_start, null, null, _append(.[3]; _append(.[2]; ""))]
        elif $c == $delim then
            [$s_next_value, null, _append(.[2]; ""), .[3]]
        elif $c == $quot then
            [$s_read_quoted, [], .[2], .[3]]
        else
            [$s_read_value, [$c], .[2], .[3]]
        end;
    def _do_read_value($c):
        if $c == $nl then
            [$s_start, null, null, _append(.[3]; _append(.[2]; .[1]|implode))]
        elif $c == $delim then
            [$s_next_value, null, _append(.[2]; .[1]|implode), .[3]]
        else
            [$s_read_value, _append(.[1]; $c), .[2], .[3]]
        end;
    def _do_read_quoted($c):
        if $c == $quot then
            [$s_escape, .[1], .[2], .[3]]
        else
            [$s_read_quoted, _append(.[1]; $c), .[2], .[3]]
        end;
    def _do_escape($c):
        if $c == $nl then
            [$s_start, null, null, _append(.[3]; _append(.[2]; .[1]|implode))]
        elif $c == $delim then
            [$s_next_value, null, _append(.[2]; .[1]|implode), .[3]]
        else
            [$s_read_quoted, _append(.[1]; $c), .[2], .[3]]
        end;
    def _do_final($c):
        .;
    def _do_finalize:
        if .[0] == $s_start then
            [$s_final, null, null, .[3]]
        elif .[0] == $s_next_value then
            [$s_final, null, null, _append(.[3]; [""])]
        elif .[0] == $s_read_value then
            [$s_final, null, null, _append(.[3]; _append(.[2]; .[1]|implode))]
        elif .[0] == $s_read_quoted then
            [$s_final, null, null, _append(.[3]; _append(.[2]; .[1]|implode))]
        elif .[0] == $s_escape then
            [$s_final, null, null, _append(.[3]; _append(.[2]; .[1]|implode))]
        else # .[0] == $s_final
            .
        end;
    reduce explode[] as $c (
        [$s_start,null,null,[]];
        do_if($c != $skip;
            if .[0] == $s_start then
                _do_start($c)
            elif .[0] == $s_next_value then
                _do_next_value($c)
            elif .[0] == $s_read_value then
                _do_read_value($c)
            elif .[0] == $s_read_quoted then
                _do_read_quoted($c)
            elif .[0] == $s_escape then
                _do_escape($c)
            else # .[0] == $s_final
                _do_final($c)
            end
        )
    )
    | _do_finalize[3][];
def parse_delimited($delim; $quot; $nl; $skip):
    _parse_delimited($delim; $quot; $nl; $skip);
def parse_delimited($delim; $quot; $nl):
    parse_delimited($delim; $quot; $nl; "\r");
def parse_delimited($delim; $quot):
    parse_delimited($delim; $quot; "\n");
def parse_delimited($delim):
    parse_delimited($delim; "\"");
def parse_csv:
    parse_delimited(",");
```

For your data, you would want to change the delimiter to semicolons.

```
$ cat se.csv
-21.3214077;55.4851413;Ruizia cordata
-21.3213078;55.4849803;Cossinia pinnata
$ jq -R 'parse_delimited(";")' se.csv
[
  "-21.3214077",
  "55.4851413",
  "Ruizia cordata"
]
[
  "-21.3213078",
  "55.4849803",
  "Cossinia pinnata"
]
```

This will work fine for most inputs to parse a line at a time, but if your data has literal newlines, you will want to read the entire file as a string.

```
$ cat input.csv
Year,Make,Model,Description,Price
1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""",,5000.00
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00
$ jq -Rs 'parse_csv' input.csv
[
  "Year",
  "Make",
  "Model",
  "Description",
  "Price"
]
[
  "1997",
  "Ford",
  "E350",
  "ac, abs, moon",
  "3000.00"
]
[
  "1999",
  "Chevy",
  "Venture \"Extended Edition\"",
  "",
  "4900.00"
]
[
  "1999",
  "Chevy",
  "Venture \"Extended Edition, Very Large\"",
  "",
  "5000.00"
]
[
  "1996",
  "Jeep",
  "Grand Cherokee",
  "MUST SELL!\nair, moon roof, loaded",
  "4799.00"
]
```

Comment: This fails if the last field is empty.

Comment: The bug is on `_do_finalize`, in the case where the last character is a delimiter. In that case, instead of saving `.[2]`, it discards it. Replacing it with something like delimiter on `_do_next_value` fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

A version of Jstaabs answer that avoids storing the whole dictionary structure in memory before printing, in case the CSV file is large.

```py
import csv, json, sys

for r in csv.DictReader(sys.stdin):
    print(dict(r))
```

Note this outputs JSON lines format and not exactly JSON.

Here's a version which outputs a proper JSON array, at the expense of being longer.

```py
import csv, json, sys

sys.stdout.write('[')

first = True
for r in csv.DictReader(sys.stdin):
    if not first:
        sys.stdout.write(',')
    first = False
    json.dump(dict(r), sys.stdout)

sys.stdout.write(']')
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a php one-liner solution:

```
php -r 'echo json_encode(array_map(''str_getcsv'', file(''file.csv'')));'
```

If you need to specify a different delimiter:

```
php -r 'echo json_encode(array_map(fn($line) => str_getcsv($line, '';''), file(''file.csv'')));'
```

You might also use some flags when using json_decode:

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php