# shell script for adding data in file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, perl, sh

I have the file say sample1.txt in linux env with comma separated values: below

```
"zc52","FS_SE",20-JUN-19,"P1C217.DB.ATC.COM  - 636","" 
 "p214","FS_MG",16-OCT-20,"","" 
 "x901","FS_TC",01-APR-21,"","" 
 "r750","FS_SP",06-JUL-21,"",
```

I need the output in below format having 1 million records, how can i do it.

```
{"id":"zc52","role":"FS_SE","created_time_stamp":"20-JUN-19, q_id":"P1C217.DB.ATC.COM - 636"}
{"id":"p214","role":"FS_MG","created_time_stamp":"16-OCT-20"}
{"id":"x901","role":"FS_TC","created_time_stamp":"01-APR-21"}
{"id":"r750","role":"FS_SP","created_time_stamp":"06-JUL-21"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting CSV to JSON in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780761/converting-csv-to-json-in-bash)

Comment: thanks, can you provide how can i add these into my script to get the above data .

Comment: Where are you stuck here? SO is here to help with existing code attempts. Please [edit] yours into the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would choose an other language for this task because it's a little difficult to parse a quoted CSV accurately with bash.

With Ruby it's real easy:

```sh
echo 'id,role,created_time_stamp,q_id' |
ruby -rcsv -rjson -e 'CSV.new(ARGF, headers: true).each{|r| puts r.to_hash.reject{|_,v| v.empty?}.to_json}' - file.csv
```

`file.csv`:

```
"zc52","FS_SE",20-JUN-19,"P1C217.DB.ATC.COM  - 636",""
"p214","FS_MG",16-OCT-20,"",""
"x901","FS_TC",01-APR-21,"",""
"r750","FS_SP",06-JUL-21,"",""
```

output:

```json
{"id":"zc52","role":"FS_SE","created_time_stamp":"20-JUN-19","q_id":"P1C217.DB.ATC.COM  - 636"}
{"id":"p214","role":"FS_MG","created_time_stamp":"16-OCT-20"}
{"id":"x901","role":"FS_TC","created_time_stamp":"01-APR-21"}
{"id":"r750","role":"FS_SP","created_time_stamp":"06-JUL-21"}
```

**remark:** What you want to generate isn't a valid JSON but a lump of JSON objects.