# How to get brew list as JSON output

Tags: json, bash, homebrew, jq

I am running `brew list --versions` to get this list:

```bash
    user@mac ~ [1]> brew list --versions
    fish 3.7.0
    ncurses 6.4
    pcre2 10.43
    syncthing 1.27.4
    appcleaner 3.6.8
    teamviewer 15.51.6
```

How can I put the output to a json object like this:

```json
[
   {
      "name":"fish",
      "version":"3.7.0"
   },
   {
      "name":"ncurses",
      "version":"6.4"
   }
]
```

Comment: This may be very similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780761/converting-csv-to-json-in-bash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get directly json format with `brew info`:

```
brew info --json --installed | jq 'map({name, version:.installed[0].version})'
```